# Redirecting output of script called from within Flask, into its own log file

Tags: python, logging, flask, stdout, io-redirection

One of the user options in my Flask application is to trigger a web-scrape. The output of this process (and indeed *any* external process, and the output of the main Flask app itself) is stdout which is the terminal in which I've started my main Flask app.

I wish to maintain the overall Flask log in the terminal, while forcing the log from the scraping process into its own file (for downloading). So given:

```
@app.route("/download-log", methods=["GET"])
def downloadlog():
    # Check for valid file and assign it to `inbound_file`
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as log:
        contents = log.read()
        response = make_response(contents)
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=log.txt"
        return response
```

.. which is working well, I need **log.txt** (currently just a `touch`ed file for proof-of-concept) to be the log from the scraping process, which I call thus:

```
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required                                 # Use of @login_required decorator
def scrape():
    scraper.scrape('/path/to/URLs.csv', ['manager'])
```

where `scraper` is a standalone python script that can and does run off its own bat normally, but is being called from within the Flask app here. `scraper.py` uses `print` statements for logging. I know how to redirect stdout into a file when calling a script itself, but how can I get the stdout of scraper.py into a file when it has been invoked from the Flask app?

I've taken the example given here stackoverflow.com/a/6386990 and applied just in `scraper.py`. It implements log-style logging alright, but the whole application's log as well as the log from scraper is still being redirected into `log.txt`.

Comment: Does setting `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')` in `scraper` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

edit scraper.py and add a redirect to a log file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('log.txt','wt')
```